# Program not printing out string from text file c++

Tags: c++, string, function

I am trying to read a certain line from a text file using a function for later use, but it does not seem to be returning a string. Function below:

```
std::vector<std::string> TextArray(string filePath) {
    int arrayNum = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> stringArray;
    ifstream file (filePath);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file,str)){
        stringArray.push_back(str);
    }
    return stringArray;//returns an array
}
```

Inside main:

```
std::vector<std::string> fileString = TextArray("c:/computerAi/saved");
std::cout << fileString[1] << std::endl;
```

I get an error saying "Vector subscript out of range"

Comment: Try fileString[0] instead.

Comment: When you step through your program with a debugger, how nany times the line with `push_back` us executed?

Comment: Are you sure `c:/computerAi/saved` will always contain at least two lines? Like you're trying to refer to fileString[1] while it can be empty at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the path may be the problem. `"c:/computerAi/saved"` is not a valid path. It should be `"C:\\computerAi\\saved"`. The double backslashes are necessary because backslash is the escape character in C/C++. If the file stream failed to open, then the vector might be empty. Also, I'm assuming here that `C:\computerAi\saved` is actually a file and not a directory.

Also, as bvj mentioned in a comment, subscript 1 is the second element in the vector, not the first. So, if you were wanting the first element, try `fileString[0]` instead of `fileString[1]`.

**Edit:** I still suspect that the path is the problem. The following program works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


std::vector<std::string> TextArray(std::string filePath)
{
    int arrayNum = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> stringArray;
    std::ifstream file(filePath.c_str());
        std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file,str))
    {
        stringArray.push_back(str);
    }

    return stringArray;//returns an array
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> fileString = TextArray("c:\\temp\\testing.txt");
    std::cout << fileString[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried this program with an invalid path (a file that did not exist,) I got the exact behavior described by the question. When I tried it with a valid path, it returned the second line of the input file, exactly as expected.

Comment: Note: a `/` is valid in paths, the path beginning with a lower case 'c' is fishy though.

Comment: C:\computerAi is a directory

Comment: Thanks I will try this after school!